# How to change attribute "name" of ion-input when its value changes?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an hybrid app using Ionic3+AngularJS, and I'm stuck on this:

I have an input like this:

```
<ion-input name="test" type="number" placeholder="0" text-center></ion-input>
```

When the user changes the value of this input, **I need that the attribute "name" changes its value too**, like this:

```
<ion-input name="test-changed" type="number" placeholder="0" text-center></ion-input>
```

Is it even possible?
Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change your template to:

```
<ion-input [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange()" type="number" placeholder="0" text-center></ion-input>
```

And in the component ts file:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {

    public value: string;
    public name: string = 'test';

    onValueChange() {
        this.name = 'test-changed';
    }

}
```

If you want that the name become `test-changed` only if there is something written in the input you could change the method `onValueChange()` to:

```
this.name = this.value ? 'test-changed' : 'test';
```

Comment: Can you do this for disabling/enabling an ion-input element when a button is clicked?

Comment: @DerryckDX You can try to do something like `<ion-input [disabled]=“condition” value=“value”>` where `condition` is changed when the button is clicked. I have not tried it tough, and I recall that there where some issues with the `disabled` attribute in ionic inputs (because it was not propagated to the nested input), but maybe that was fixed (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5280).